# Make GDM accessible only remotely via XDMCP, while console remains in text mode

Tags: 10.04, server, gdm, console, xdmcp

I have a 10.04 server and I have installed gnome-desktop on it so that I can do some of work in a nicer way. I connect to gdm remotely via XDMCP (Hummingbird Exceed) but at the same time I want the console to remain in text mode. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a local console, a console via a VM control center, etc.?  Are you looking for speed, stability, etc. with the text-only console?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is currently, the XDMCP protocol is there for remote logins for thin client machines and that's how the functionality is implemented.

What is it you need gdm to do? I just wrote a gdm greeter.

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl-alt-F1 to escape GDM, or launch an xterm- or terminator-only session?  Or ssh to your own box (you can do this locally or remotely).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC I was able to do it (loong time ago) by making the `[servers]` section of gdm.conf empty. By default, it contains `0=/usr/bin/X11/X` or such, which runs the first local server. (update: hey, I googled it up at
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard#Disable_the_local_X_server_in_gdm.2C_enable_XDMCP_connections as well)